# Angular http post - Fail to load resource: The network connection was lost

Tags: ios, angularjs, ajax

I seem to get the following error on my mobile site...

"Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost".

I get this when I use angular to make a http post to a controller. This error only occurs when visiting my website via an iphone. I do not get this error on other mobile devices. Could you advise??

Comment: Please post the code and we can help you.

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Can you load directly the api server/resource in Safari?